# Connect Pods from one cluster to a pod in aother cluster without using k8s service

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, cloud-foundry, kubernetes-pod

We have two k8s clusters:

Cluster details:

```
Cluster 1:
Pod Network: 172.16.1.0/24
Node Network: 172.16.2.0/24

Cluster 2:
Pod Network: 172.16.3.0/24
Node Network: 172.16.4.0/24
```

All these networks are connectivity to one another.

Suppose we have 3 pods in each clusters

```
Cluster1-Pod1: IP: 172.16.1.1 
Cluster1-Pod2: IP: 172.16.1.2
Cluster1-Pod3: IP: 172.16.1.3

Cluster2-Pod1: IP: 172.16.3.1 
Cluster2-Pod2: IP: 172.16.3.2
Cluster2-Pod3: IP: 172.16.3.3
```

How can one access the apps of pods in `cluster2` from `cluster1` without creating a `k8s` service using Pod IP or `hostname`.
Any solution available to publish/advertise pods `IP/hostname` from one cluster to another?
If creating a service is mandatory, any options to achieve it without Type: LoadBlanacer or Ingress?

Appreciate any inputs.

Comment: how about service type as NodePort

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I would prefer a solution without using service.

Comment: not sure if that is possible. You might have to consider a hybrid cluster

Comment: Are you sure you are not confusing nodes with clusters?
Because if these pods exist on different nodes, within the same cluster, then you can simply access the pod with its IP.

Comment: Because otherwise, it is not possible to connect to your pod outside the cluster without making your pod public by a service(NodePort, LoadBalancer) or Ingress.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure you are not confusing nodes with clusters? Because if these pods exist on different nodes, within the same cluster, then you can simply access the pod with its IP.

Otherwise, it is not possible to connect to your pod outside the cluster without making your pod public by a service(NodePort, LoadBalancer) or Ingress.